# i want to change the font size in web application using c# code

Tags: .net

If A Change the Font Size in other page . It will automatically change in the Default Font Size

I will change the font in Settings .It will be Update in My database And The database Font Size Is Fetch.
that fetch font size i have to given in My texarea